# Can't connect to TP-LINK router admin page from a specific computer

Tags: networking, router

I have a TP-LINK Archer C2 AC 750 wireless router. I should be able to access the admin page at 192.168.0.1, and indeed I can from one computer. However, from my Dell XPS 12 running Windows 8.1 Professional, I cannot access the admin page from any browser (the browser simply times out and says it is unable to connect). Note, I can successfully ping the IP address.

I was previously able to connect to the router via the Dell XPS 12. However, I had configured the router so the default gateway was 10.0.0.1 instead of 192.168.0.1. With that configuration, I was able to access the router admin page at 10.0.0.1. However, I recently changed the default gateway back to 192.168.0.1, and now my computer will no longer access the admin page. The router does assign my computer an IP address, and I do have internet access through the router. The only problem is that I cannot get to the admin page.

I assume there is something I must reset on my computer to get this to work, but I have no idea what. I have already tried `netsh winsock reset`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly accessing `192.168.0.1` in your browser, which on my home internet is mapped to a modem instead of the router, so it may map to something else on that computer

Try `tplinkwifi.net`.

Another thing that could be causing that issue is if the port settings aren't mapping correctly for that IP address.

So, while you can ping it successfully, your browser will be trying to connect to ports `80` or `8080`, and *they* may fail, while the parent IP does not.

Comment: tplinkwifi.net doesn't work either. How would I go about checking whether the port settings are mapped correctly and fixing them?

Comment: If you ping `tplinkwifi.net` does cmd tell you it's at 192.168.0.1?

Comment: @Quill: Yes, it does.